# How do I smooth these sharp edges?

Tags: object-mode

Here is the picture of my object:

[image]

As you can see there are sharp edges from the top to the bottom of the object.
But the thing is I haven't found any solution to counter this however.

The only solution I had tried is **Object > Shade Smooth**.
But here are it's results:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?, thanks!

Comment: Hello, are your talking about the shading or about the contour? These are 2 different things. If you're talking about the contour, you can bevel the edges

Comment: I'm talking about this:
https://all3dp.com/2/blender-smooth-shading-simply-explained/

Comment: you say "Is there any way to solve this?", what are you refering to? what bothers you in the image?

Comment: The black glows somehow bother me.

Comment: @FerbiZides you could fix that by auto smooth

Answer (score 6):

At first, to make the smooth shading look less weird you should enable *Normals* > *Auto Smooth* in the *Object Data Properties*.

[image: auto smooth]

If you now also want the edges to be smoothed or rounded off, I would suggest you use the *Bevel Modifier*. This way you can non-destructively smoothen the edges and make changes afterwards if needed.

Go to the *Modifier Properties* tab, click on *Add Modifier* and choose *Bevel*. Then you can adjust the *Amount* and *Segments* to your liking. The *Limit Method* is by default set to *Angle*, with a default value of 30°. On my model I've lowered it to 24° to get the bottom edges beveled as well. What I would also suggest is to disable *Geometry* > *Loop Slide* and enable *Shading* > *Harden Normals*.

[image: bevel modifier]

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite ways to do this is by combining a Bevel modifier with a SubSurf modifier.

SubSurf is great because it can't be beat in terms of smoothing out the geometry of your model. Only problem is it takes the manual addition of edge loops all along every edge you want to keep relatively sharp, which is time-consuming and difficult to edit.

[image]

If you don't add these in you get a model that looks like this:

[image]

Not great.

However, if you use a Bevel modifier, with the profile set to 1, and set the Limit Method to Angle, you can almost get 100% of your edge-loops for free.

[image]

It's not entirely fool-proof though. Spots like here on the bot

[image]

So in this example it's not exactly 100% automatic, 90% of the objects you try this method on, this will get you what you need.

We just need to do two things:

Select the front face and press "I" to inset it a bit.

[image]

Then in edge select mode, go to *Select>Sharp Edges*. This get's us nearly all we want.

[image]
[image]

We just need to figure out a way to get these edges in there.
[image]

Which in this exact scenario we can do by using *Select > Loops > Edge Loops*.

[image]
[image]

And then *Ctrl+E > Edge Bevel Weight* and type in 1 on the numpad.

[image]

Now we have all the edges that we want beveled marked as such.

[image]

Incidentally, this is what the first versions of HardOps did way back in the day; automate this whole process to make it a 1-click deal.

Now you can just push `Ctrl+1` to add a SubSurf modifier with 1 level of subdivision, and we're looking good. Also set it to shade smooth, auto smooth and, if needed, a Weighted Normal modifier.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a bevel?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry My thoughts exactly. This is a quite simple object and bevel or the _Bevel Modifier_ would be absolutely sufficient to achieve that. I would only suggest to deactivate _Loop Slide_ for the bevel.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry. [this is why](https://imgur.com/a/dhrjvwY)

Comment: @Jakemoyo You've got a point ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution (geometry absolutely bonkers though):

1. Select all of the sharp edges:

[image]

2. Bevel all of them and set the segments to 10.
3. Add 2 modifiers called "Edge Split" and "Subdivision Surface".

Detailed note for the 2 modifiers:

[image]

And if you had done all of that, this should be the result:
[image]

This solution is enough for me as I will only texture it and export it, with nothing else in mind.

Comment: Well, you could have easily selected the two outside edge loops, marked them sharp, and add a bevel or subdiv to do what you did. Though I guess you didn't explain your end result.

Comment: Or the above answer could have worked if you didn't add the two bottom sharp edges.

Comment: Okay, my answer is for if you want to change something afterwards - but now that you said you want to export it, changing the mesh by beveling it in _Edit Mode_ would be better.  However, you don't need those modifiers for that result. First of all, select all three front faces and the corresponding faces on the back. Press F to join them. Then select the edges you want to bevel and do it. If you have set the object to smooth shading and it looks weird, enable _Normals_ > _Auto Smooth_ in the _Object Data Properties_. This will give you a better geometry as well.